# ssl client_hello, unidentified data

Tags: ssl

I am trying to make sense of a SSL Client Hello packet, but I am stuck on the last view bytes.

`0000   16 03 00 00 58 01 00 00 54 03 03 52 f3 8a b2 f6  ....X...T..R....

    0010   35 b8 08 39 25 5f 61 73 d5 b6 af 4d 3c 1a 2d 70  5..9%_as...M<.-p

    0020   58 2e be 8a 89 b6 5c e1 9a 3f 81 00 00 18 00 35  X.....\..?.....5

    0030   00 2f 00 0a 00 05 00 04 00 38 00 32 00 13 00 66  ./.......8.2...f

    0040   00 39 00 33 00 16 01 00 00 13 ff 01 00 01 00 00  .9.3............

    0050   0d 00 0a 00 08 04 02 04 01 02 01 02 02           .............`

What I got so far:
16: msg type
03 00: SSL version
00 58: Record Length
01: Handshake Type - Client_Hello
00 00 54: Message Length
03 03: Client preferred version
52 f3 8a b2 f6 35 ... 5c e1 9a 3f 81: random data/ timestamp
00: Session ID Length 0
00 18: Ciphersuit Length
00 35 .. 00 16: cipher suites
01: compression method length
00: compression method
00 13 ff 01 00 01 00 00 0d 00 0a 00 08 04 02 04 01 02 01 02 02: what is this ?
At first a thought it was challenge data, but it seems to be constant over all the packages.

My main guide for deciphering the packet was: http://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/webprogramming/HTTP_SSL.html (under Client_Hello)

(sorry for the bad formatting)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bytes after the compression method are TLS extensions (see [RFC 5246, section 7.4.1.2 Client Hello](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246#section-7.4.1.2)).

```
0x13 0x00    length of extensions
```

The first one is the **renegotiation_info** extension (see [RFC 5746, Section 3.2 Extension Definition](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5746#section-3.2)):

```
0xff 0x01    renegotiation_info
0x00 0x01    length
0x00         0x00 for inital handshakes
```

The other one is the **signature_algorithms** extension ([RFC 5246, section 7.4.1.4.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246#section-7.4.1.4.1)):

```
0x00 0x0d    signature_algorithm
0x00 0x0a    length
0x00 0x08    HashAlgorithm: none, SignatureAlgorithm: 0x08
0x04 0x02    HashAlgorithm: sha-256, SignatureAlgorithm: dsa
0x04 0x01    HashAlgorithm: sha-256, SignatureAlgorithm: rsa
0x02 0x01    HashAlgorithm: sha-1, SignatureAlgorithm: rsa
0x02 0x02    HashAlgorithm: sha-1, SignatureAlgorithm: dsa
```